# Just Android or also developer questions?

Tags: support, scope

I am new to Android Enthusiasts, and I was wondering:
Is this site just for discussing android apps/android system, or can you also come here for help on Android app coding issues?

Comment: Hint: every SE site has that `help/on-topic` page [eldarerathis is referring to in his answer](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/1932/16575). So when usure, that's the first place to check. And, Rumanoid: Thanks for caring!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When in doubt, every Stack Exchange site has a help center page listed as [What topics can I ask about here?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) It lays out the site's scope and acceptable topics.

Our site's help page (linked above) describes the purpose of this site:

> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device
>
> then this is the right place to ask. Basically, what problem (with your Android device) are you trying to solve?

It goes on to say:

> Please note the following topics are expressly ***off-topic*** here:
>
> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)
>     ...

So no, this site is not for development questions. You should visit [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) for those questions.